# Angularjs pass an array to custom filter as parameter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

When defining a custom filter in Angularjs like below I'm passing in the data set I want filtered and an array to serve as the filter values:

**Toggle buttons state passed in an array**
[image]

**Parameter array value passed into the filter**
[image]

How the filter is called:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="item in data | filterStats:filters">
```

The custom filter checks which values in the array should apply by filtering the data set in ng-repeat.

```
   .filter('filterStats', function () {
        return function (items, paramArray) {
        var isFilterEmpty = true;
            angular.forEach(paramArray, function (value, key) {
            if (value == 0) {
                isFilterEmpty = false;
            }
        });

        if(!isFilterEmpty) 
        //More logic
   }
}
```

**Problem:** The problem is that the array parameter does not seems to be able to loop using a forEach inside of the custom filter. The parameter array shows [`Array[0]`] therefore seems empty.
Can anyone please provide guidance on this matter? Can one pass an Array as a custom filter parameter? What am I missing?

Tx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are probably defining `filters` as an Array but are using it like an Object.

You haven't put any indexes in the array, so it is empty. By doing `filters.Limited = '-1'` this is adding **named properties** to the array but the actual length of the array is still 0.

```
var a = [];
a.length; // 0
a.something = '123';
a.length // still 0
a[0] = '456';
a.length; // now 1
```

Instead, if you define your `filters` variable as an Object instead of an Array I imagine your code will work as you expect.

`$scope.filters = {};`