# AngularJS: how to give array of values to filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

How to pass array of values as filter in angularjs

My scenario

cuisines json: `["food", "Alcohol","Thai"]`

catorigeres json :`["home", "office","school"]`

values with cuisines and categories :

```
[{
    "_id": "1",
    "businessTypeName": "Pizza Hut",
    "cus_name": ["food","Thai"],
    "cat_name": ["home", "school"],

}, {
    "_id": "2",
    "businessTypeName": "Chicken Hut",
    "cus_name":["Alcohol","Thai"],
    "cat_name": ["office", "home"],
}, {
    "_id": "3",
    "businessTypeName": "Fish Hut",
    "bussiness_url": "/dist/images/loop_image_sample_3.png",
    "cus_name": ["Thai"],
    "cat_name": ["office", "school"],

}]
```

cuisines and categories are of in checkbox if i click anyone it will append the array of values to {{selected}}

my question is how to filter values in  `{{selected}}` to listing_loop div

[my plunker demo](https://embed.plnkr.co/fAqCr6/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37188106/angularjs-pass-an-array-to-custom-filter-as-parameter

Comment: yes see that can you explain how can we do it in my scenario ?

Comment: @RamanaaGj, have you checked [the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3N1fDVaD1G1ZeKMkgWq3?p=preview)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do that in html alone.

You can add a filtering function to the scope:

```
$scope.customFilter = function(value, index, array) {
      // make sure `value.id` is a string
      return ["food","Thai","Alcohol"].indexOf(value.id);
}
```

and using like this in HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="set in get | filter:customFilter"></div>
```

Comment: your plunker doesn't have `<div ng-repeat="set in get..."></div>` in it. add the full example, and I'll update with the filter, or do it yourself, it's just a few lines. If helped, you can upvote or accept my answer

Comment: i have three api values one for 

categories  `["home","office","school"]`

and

cuisines`["food","Alcohol","Thai","Asian"]`

and all values as in this api  `https://api.myjson.com/bins/4m12o`

cuisines and categories are of in checkbox if i selected those values means it will come to `{{selected}}` array

in that `{{selected}}` array i want to filter out from all values ..

i think you may understood what i except

Comment: do you want to filter by `cat_name` or `cus_name`?

Comment: want filter by cat_name